# Create a Qgis Icon based on an existing Icon

Tags: python, open-source, gis, gdal, qgis

I am in need to create a Qgis icon similar to the existing Selection Qgis icon [Select features by are or single click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ojbpu.png). I will create a new Icon to do exactly what the existing Qgis icon does and add some more script to it.

1 - I need to get the code for this existing Icon [Select features by are or single click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ojbpu.png).

2 - Add the following code to it:

```
layer = iface.activeLayer()

selection = layer.selectedFeatures()

print len(selection)

for f in layer.selectedFeatures():
    layer_xml = iface.addRasterLayer(f['tms'], f['name'])
```

Any help on that will be very appreciated.